# Xcode keeps on crash on modification of XIB file in interface builder

Tags: xcode, interface-builder

i am trying to modify one xib file in my IOS project, xcode crashes immediately on try to drag UILabel or any other element..Any clues will be appreciated..

Below is crash report..

```
Process:         Xcode [22769]
Path:            /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode
Identifier:      com.apple.dt.Xcode
Version:         4.3.2 (1177)
Build Info:      IDEApplication-1177000000000000~6
App Item ID:     497799835
App External ID: 7171108
Code Type:       X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [22632]

Date/Time:       2013-04-03 20:12:57.262 +0530
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.7.5 (11G56)
Report Version:  9

Interval Since Last Report:          1804 sec
Crashes Since Last Report:           2
Per-App Interval Since Last Report:  244 sec
Per-App Crashes Since Last Report:   2

Crashed Thread:  0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000

Application Specific Information:
ProductBuildVersion: 4E2002
ASSERTION FAILURE in /SourceCache/IDEInterfaceBuilder/IDEInterfaceBuilder-    2182/Framework/Document/IBDocument.m:6465
Details:  Cannot turn on autolayout for a document that doesn't support it:  <IBCocoaTouchDocument: 0x40230c320>
Object:   <IBCocoaTouchDocument: 0x40230c320>
Method:   -setUseAutolayout:
Thread:   <NSThread: 0x40010a1e0>{name = (null), num = 1}
Hints:   None
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the autolayout, check your deployment target needs to be 6 or higher.

Comment: There is no option for deployment target 6.. max is 5.1.. It seems i need to update my xcode.. Is there any other way? Can i disable autolayout somewhere?

Comment: Yes you can disable autolayout check this page for more information http://www.goodbyehelicopter.com/2012/02/arggh-xcode-4-3-auto-layout-is-on-by-default-how-to-turn-off-auto-layout/